# Azure Function can't connect to azure sql database. Package error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to connect my azure function to my `azure sql database`. When trying connection.open() it gives the following error.

> Executed 'ClientID2' (Failed, Id=22ad8465-45f5-4fff-ba90-f0ff7d0ee465,
> Duration=5895ms) [2021-11-25T10:49:57.575Z] System.Private.CoreLib:
> Exception while executing function: ClientID2.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient: The type initializer for
> 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

The connection itself runs on .net 5.0 framework, but not in .net core 3.1 .

```
[FunctionName("ClientID2")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        string requestBody = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            log.LogInformation("Function process");

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Connection_Database")))
            {
                connection.Open();
```

[Packages installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1AYy.png)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Best regards

EDIT:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>Client_ID</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.30" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Local.Settings.Json

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        "Connection_Database": Connection string from azure sql database
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your .csproj file code

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT added to original

Comment: Could you please share your local.host.json

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT in connection string i copied the connection string from azure. the string is passed to function and it was tested in .net 5.0 and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, but not sure if it is the correct way.

Had to put the System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll and System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll directly in bin folder of project.

Next, according to this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68765032/7417020)

I added to the .csproj the following

```
<ItemGroup>
        <FunctionsPreservedDependencies Include="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll" />
        <FunctionsPreservedDependencies Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

And then it worked